# My Android phone screen is un-usable, how do I transfer all my data to a new phone?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, 2.2-froyo, contacts, backup, data-recovery

My current phone (Samsung Galaxy POP) running Andoid 2.2 has all its data including contacts and messages stored in the SD card + SIM card. However the touch screen of that phone has been damaged and so the phone is unusable now on it's own. I have purchased a new phone (Xperia SL) online which which runs Android 4.0 and does not have an SD card slot, it only has an internal memory. My question is, how do I transfer all my data including contacts and text messages from my old phone to my new phone. Since my old phone is practically unusable, I'll have to connect it to my PC and prob back up my data and thereafter transfer it to the new phone. Could somebody suggest me some resources which will guide me on how to backup my data between phones by using the PC as a medium. I tried looking up on Google for help and could not find any good solutions for this issue.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the reasons a Smartphone without a SDCard slot is an absolute no-go for me: If you cannot access the device anymore (e.g. the device no longer powers up), and don't want your data "in the cloud" -- you can say Good-bye to your data...

But to your issue:

### SIM card

As you state all your contact data are on the SIM card -- no worries for those. As soon as you stick the SIM card into the new device, those contact data are there. Unless you've used a miniSIM until now and the new device only supports microSIM (or any other reason you cannot simply put the SIM card into the new phone). So in case of that, you can...

- open your contacts app on the old phone
- tap the *menu* key
- select *Export/Import*
- Export all contacts to your SDCard

Then, we handle those data together with the other SDCard stuff.

### Text messages

They are a completely different issue. Here you would need a special backup app to retrieve them. As with the contacts "export", this would also require you to at least be able to use your old phone somehow.

If your PC runs Windows, you might want to take a look at [MyPhoneExplorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fjsoft.myphoneexplorer.client), which comes with an Android Client (the link points there) and a PC component. Not running Windows myself, I can only report hear-say -- but it should be able to synchronize your Android device with your PC, including contacts, text messages, and more. It even lets you remote-control your device to a degree, according to the comments. A similiarly powerful tool for Windows users is [Moborobo](http://www.moborobo.com/index.html), also worth a look (see [AddictiveTips](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/moborobo-the-most-comprehensive-android-ios-manager-yet-review/) for a description).

Not being on Windows, but being able to use your old device's screen at least basically, [Message Sync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.messagesync) can export your messages on the old and import them on the new device; [SMS Backup & Restore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.riteshsahu.SMSBackupRestore) would be an alternative choice.

### SDCard

- Take out the SDCard from the old phone, put it into a card reader, and attach it to your PC. Your PC should show this as a new drive.
- Attach your new phone to your computer using a USB cable. It should offer you to select a connection mode. Depending on what's available, chose either *USB Mass Storage* or *MTP*. Again, your PC should now offer this as a new drive.
- Use your favorite file explorer on the PC to copy all the data from the SDCard to your new device
- ***Safely remove*** and disconnect both devices from your PC
- If you had to export your contacts on the old phone via the contacts app, use the same procedure to import them to your new device

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have tried it or not, but use Kies、 mobileGo or MobiKin Assistant for Android. I think your phone will be automatically detected; no need for touch screen. Then, backup all the things you want. Then, unplug it and connect the new phone and restore the data.

Answer (score 0):

Or just use an OTG cable and plug in a mouse